# Numpy Array Reshaping takes 3 hours. Is there any way to make it faster?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have written a function that reshapes the numpy array per given window length.
The function does the following.

[image: Array Reshaping]

My function as follows:

```
def w_s(df, l):
    """
    Convert numpy array into desired shape with lag 1.
    Args:
        df (numpy.ndarray): Numpy array.
        l (integer): Length of the sample window.
    
    Returns:
        Returns numpy array in a desired shape to be used in decision trees.
    """
    data = np.zeros((l, 1))
    data = np.append(data, df)
    data = data[l:]
    for i in range(1, l):
        s1 = np.roll(df,0-i)
        data = np.append(data,s1)
    data = data.reshape(l, len(df)).T
    
    return data[:-(l-1)]
```

I have two arrays with the length of `1780000`. The function takes around 3 hours.

`CPU times: user 5min 20s, sys: 43min 45s, total: 49min 6s Wall time: 3h 5min 46s`

My machine is Mac M1. I am running this on Jupyter cell where server runs on Firefox. How can I do this faster?

Comment: `np.append` in a loop is probably always a bad solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, 5)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: As a note, the 3h wall time on your computer is odd. On my intel i7 it is 12.2 us with `sliding_window_view` and 48.8 ms for your `w_s`, when working on `np.arange(1_780_000)` with a window of length 5.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with the function, I mean the way I do it. 28.8 ms wall time now on my MAC as well.